# calling activity in another package

Tags: android, android-intent, package, android-activity

so i have an application which has a default package as `com.android`.

within this package i have two packages as `android.audio` and `android.video`.

now i need to call `activity1` from `android.audio` from `activity2` in `android.video`.

i have tried using something like

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("android.video","android.audio.activity1");
startActivity(i);
```

but this doesnt seem to work.
what is the right way to do it? where have i gone wrong?
i m not able to navigate to any activity outside the package.

EDIT: 
this is how it is declared in the manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_title" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_title"
        android:name=".WeaveActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="android.login.LoginActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="android.login.RegisterActivity"></activity>

    <activity android:name="android.video.activity2"></activity>

     <activity android:name="android.audio.activity1"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: package means java package or different apk?

Comment: So agarwal answer is correct ... You just made mistake in AndeoidManifest.xml

Comment: i have edited the question. please do take a look at it.

Comment: once place your complete manifeast file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my entire package structure by giving project package name as `com.android` and rest of the sub packages as `com.android.audio` and `com.android.video` and now it seems to work. thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(activity2.this,activity1.class);
startActivity(i);
```

use above code and add these activity in your manifeast file.
AS you told your package name is com.android

```
<activity android:name=".audio.activity1"></activity>
<activity android:name=".video.activity2"></activity>
```

or use complete path as below

```
<activity android:name="com.android.audio.activity1"></activity>
<activity android:name="com.android.video.activity2"></activity>
```

and a small suggestion for you never use your package name as com.android because if use then while submitting the app to Google Play it wont accept it as the package com.android is used for android SDK.

Comment: it still gives force close with the error `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android/android.audi.activity1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`
i have declared it in the manifest as `android.audio.activity1` and `android.video.activity2`

Comment: have you added .audio.activity1 in manifeast file this error causes if you wont add or add in wrong way then

Comment: would you need any other info?

Comment: Post full manifest ... Seems like it is named com.android and activities are in android.*

Comment: yea wouldnt the complete class path be different? as @Selvin sai, it is named com.android and the sub packages are named android.audio. could that be a problem?

Comment: yes i did try the post and it gives me the same error. whats interesting is that it gives error with activity path as {com.android/android.audio.activity1}. is that the package path it is searching for? will i have to rewrite my entire package structure?

Comment: try by placing dotbefore android.audio.activity1 and android.video.activity2

Comment: Try any other package name instead of "com.android"

Answer (score 0):

```
in manifest decalre like
```

`<activity android:name=”.activity1”`
`android:label=”Activity 1”>`
`<intent-filter>`
`<action android:name=”android.audio.activity1”/>`
`<category android:name=”android.intent.category.DEFAULT”/>`
`</intent-filter>`
`</activity>`

and while calling from any activity...
`startActivity(new Intent(“android.audio.activity1”));`
hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your package name.

I think you gave only "audi" instead of "audio"

Comment: that was an error i made during copy paste. apologies for that.